# why is GridView not rendering?

Tags: flutter

I am wondering why is it that my GridView is not rendering the widgets. I am trying to render the buttons in two columns and 2-3 rows.
The code is the following:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/wifi.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Wifi')
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/wifi.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Key/Access')
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/wifi.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Key/Access')
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/wifi.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Key/Access')
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

I get an error, in the android emulator it renders yellow and black strips instead of the buttons with the corresponding images.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with Container ( height: .. , width : double.infinity )

Or with SizedBox

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `Column` widget above the `GridView`